# Duplicate of a locked "historical significance" question?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, off-topic

This question https://serverfault.com/questions/590163/monitoring-server-statistics
Is being marked as a duplicate of
[What tool do you use to monitor your servers?](https://serverfault.com/questions/44/what-tool-do-you-use-to-monitor-your-servers)

The latter question is a locked offtopic "historically significant" question.

Should we be using those to close as duplicates?  Should that old question even still exist?  It is quite out of date, which is the reason product recommendations are offtopic.  Pointing someone at that question isn't likely to help them very much, and may even confuse them further.

What should we be doing with these questions?

Comment: *> it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here* Probably just close the new one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're concerned that the OP might be confused as to why they're being directed to that question feel free to leave them a comment explaining why their question is off-topic, and what about the duplicate may help them.

---

As for why historical significance questions continue to exist, this should be self-evident: **They have *Historical Significance***. The monitoring tools list question generates ~16,000 views per year, and deleting it would deprive us of that traffic (possibly breaking a lot of external links in the process).
Because it does not meet our current topicality and quality standards it is locked to prevent new answers from being added (such answers would get very few views anyway, starting at a 0 score) - it is effectively a museum piece.

A better (and on-topic) question to ask in its place might be "What should I consider when selecting a monitoring tool?" - this is also likely to be more helpful to future users than a list of monitoring systems, and I don't think anyone has asked it yet...

Comment: **TL:DR** Some questions are traffic magnets, traffic pays the bills, keeps the doors open for the community.

Comment: @ChrisS well that's the important half of it. The other half (not breaking people's links & not gathering answers that will sit at 0 score unseen forever) is just about being a good net citizen :)

Comment: "[and I don't think anyone has asked it yet](http://serverfault.com/q/394393/50647)" I was half expecting you to have an answer there. :D